# save many UIImage to NSMutableArray without memory leak or similar method

Tags: ios, crash, uiimage, nsmutablearray, save

I am trying to do screen capturing and saving many images into NSMutableArray. Then, I will call those images and make video. I can successfully make video. However, the problem is that I can't save many images into NSMutableArray. The application crash. I would like to know how to save those images temporarily. (not in document directory).

Comment: Thanks Rob. I also can get image at 1 time and save to video. Problem is that I can't separate thread easily from UI, capture image and save to video. As a result, I am thinking to save all the images first and convert to video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will quickly run out of memory if you try to store all of those images in an array. You have two options:

1. Even though you say you don't want to save all of those images to the Documents folder, that might be your best approach. Save them to Documents, and then have your video creation process load the images one at a time and add them to the video.
2. Alternatively, you can do the `renderInContext` of your view that you want to capture directly to the `CGContextRef` that you've set up for your `CVPixelBufferRef`, do the `appendPixelBuffer`, and but then `CVPixelBufferRelease` immediately.

Either of these approaches will avoid holding all of the images in memory at any given time, mitigating the out of memory situation. I profiled both approaches, and each avoids the constantly growing consumption of memory that the loading of images to an array suffers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will follow. For your second suggestion, I am not sure how to do. For that method, I believe I will need to capture image immediately and save to video. But, I can record only up to about 10 seconds and after 10 sec, the application crash because of "Received memory warning". I have asked in this link. If possible, can you kindly answer that question? It is because that question and your second suggestion are related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055004/received-memory-warning-when-capturing-screen-and-save-to-video-ios