# Received memory warning when capturing screen and save to video ios

Tags: ios, memory, crash, screen, capture

I am now writing a  program to capture screen and convert to video. I can successfully save the video if it is less than 10 seconds. But, if more than that, I received memory warning and application crash. I wrote this code as follow. Where am I missing to release data ? I would like to know how to do.

```
-(void)captureAndSaveImage
{

if(!stopCapturing){

if (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
{
    keepTrackOfBackGroundMood++;
    NSLog(@"keepTrackOfBackGroundMood is %d",keepTrackOfBackGroundMood);

    CVReturn cvErr = kCVReturnSuccess;

    CGSize imageSize = screenCaptureAndDraw.bounds.size;


    CGFloat imageScale = 0; //if zero, it reduce processing time

    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, imageScale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    }

    [self.hiddenView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    [self.screenCaptureAndDraw.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];


    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



     image = (CGImageRef) [img CGImage];

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    CFDataRef imageData= CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));
    cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         FRAME_WIDTH2,
                                         FRAME_HEIGHT2,
                                         kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                         (void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         NULL,
                                         &pixelBuffer);


    //CFRelease(imageData);
    //CGImageRelease(image);  //I can't write this code because I am not creating it and when I check online, it say it is not my responsibility to release. If I write, the application crash immediately


    // calculate the time
    CFAbsoluteTime thisFrameWallClockTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = thisFrameWallClockTime - firstFrameWallClockTime;


    // write the sample

    BOOL appended = [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];

    if (appended) {
        NSLog (@"appended sample at time %lf and keepTrackofappended is %d", CMTimeGetSeconds(presentationTime),keepTrackofappended);
        keepTrackofappended++;
    } else {
        NSLog (@"failed to append");
        [self stopRecording];
        //self.startStopButton.selected = NO;
        screenRecord=false;
    }



}

}//stop capturing
// });


}
```

Comment: You must have a leak somewhere (at the very least, I'd uncomment the `CFRelease(imageData)` and don't forget to `CVPixelBufferRelease`). I just tested a 1200 frame capture and it was fine on my iPhone 5. And when I've tested in Instruments, allocations are flat, so unless you have an some leak, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you don't want to do the `CGImageRelease(image)`. This object was created by calling `CGImage` method of a `UIImage` object. Thus ownership was not transferred and ARC still does the memory management for your `img` object and no releasing of the `image` object is needed.

But I think you *do* want to restore your `CFRelease(imageData)`. This is an object created by `CGDataProviderCopyData`, so you own it and must clean up.

I also think you have to release the `pixelBuffer` that you created with `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` after you `appendPixelBuffer`. You can use the `CVPixelBufferRelease` function for that.

The Core Foundation memory rule is that if the function has `Copy` or `Create` in the name, you own that object and are responsible for releasing it. See the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) in the *Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation.*

I would have thought that the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or "Analyze" from the Xcode "Product" menu) would have identified this issue, as it has gotten much better at finding Core Foundation memory issues (albeit, not perfect).

Alternatively, if you run your app through the Leaks tool in Instruments (which will also show you the Allocations tool at the same time), you can take a look at your memory usage. While the video capture requires a lot of Live Bytes, in my experience it stays pretty darn flat. If it's growing, you have a leak somewhere.

Comment: Oh thanks Rob. You really help me. I think it now solve memory leak problem. I will check again with static analyzer.

Comment: @user1111 Yes, `CFRelease(imageData)` and `CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer)` (but not `CGImageRelease(image)`) should remedy the leaks.